# how to add link for the image created using javascript

Tags: image, for-loop, hyperlink, addition

how to add link for the image created using following javascript.
i tried to do somethings but nothing change
thanks for any help or replies.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var image1 = new Image()
 image1.src =="http://idealbodyweights.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1.png"
 var image2 = new Image()
 image2.src = "http://idealbodyweights.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/2.png"
 var image3 = new Image()
 image3.src = "http://idealbodyweights.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/3.png"
 var image4 = new Image()
 image4.src = "http://idealbodyweights.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/4.png"
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><img src="images/pentagg.jpg" width="720" height="90" name="slide" /></p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var step=4;
    function slideit()
    {

        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
        if(step<4)
            step++;
        else
            step=1;
        setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
    }
    slideit();
    </script>
```